# How to manually set the app window dimensions in React Native

Tags: react-native

I was wondering if it would be possible to manually set the entire app window dimension manually.
I'm aware of the [useDimensions](https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks#usedimensions) hook but I'm not interested in listening to window's dimensions changes, I'm interested in setting them.
For example I would like to set an entire app to be 50% in height of the available screen size.

I could't find any doc on this specific request.
Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try this in the root level file, like app.js or somewhere ,

```
const App = () => {
return(
<View>
<View style={{height:0.5*Dimensions.get('window').height}}>
<StackNavigatrScreen />
</View>
<View  style={{height:0.5*Dimensions.get('window').height,width:'100%'}}/>
</View>
)


}
```

and inside the stack navigator you have your enitre screens, so that it just occupies 50 percent of screen ,rather than whole

hope it helps, feel free for doubts

Comment: Wouldn't this set the dimension of a view inside the entire app? I wanted the entire app to be 50% of the screen height so that half of the screen would still be visible

Comment: what do you want to make it visible in their?